# Push Object in Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```
 var p = {
     id: null
 };
 for (var copyArray = [], i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
     copyArray.push(p);
     copyArray[i].id = (copyArray.length) - parseInt(1, 10);
 }
 console.log(copyArray);
```

All id in copyArray is getting 2 value.
Result CopyArray({id=2},{id=2},{id=2})

Doing normal push operation of object in array, and updating the index after insertion.

But somehow all id's in the copy array are getting same id
What wrong i am doing over here

Comment: Side note: `parseInt(1, 10)` is just a long-winded and inefficient way to write `1`. `parseInt` is for parsing **strings** as integers.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder what is 10 in parseInt(1,10)?

Comment: @Alex Converting to Decimal, you can also use `2`, `8`, `16` for binary, octal, hex respectively

Comment: @Alex: The radix (number base) to use. 10 (decimal) is the number base we normally write numbers in. It's 10 because each "place" in a number is a power of 10. E.g., 123 is (1 x 10²) + (2 x 10¹) + (3 x 10⁰).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Is there any resource I can read so I can advance to same knowledge level about javascript and jquery as yours?

Comment: @Alex: I didn't use any one resource, just a lot of things I've picked up over the years. My two primary references are [the specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html) and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript). MDN is more user-friendly, but is also collaboratively-edited by anyone who wants to sign up for a Mozilla account. It used to be consistently excellent; the last couple of years people have been contributing who aren't quite as rigorous and well-informed as the original authors, Still very good. Do not use w3schools.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're pushing the **same object** into the array repeatedly, and just updating the `id` property on that object as you go.

If you want multiple objects in the array, you'll need to create multiple objects:

```js
var copyArray = [];
while (copyArray.length < 3) {
  copyArray.push({
    id: copyArray.length
  });
}
snippet.log(JSON.stringify(copyArray));
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: It worked thanks.. Is there any explanation why we can't do that way,,?

Comment: @KunalVashist: The first sentence is the explanation: You're pushing the **same object** repeatedly.

Answer (score -1):

You can also create a function that will create clone for the Object:

```
JSON.clone = function(json) {
    var
        temp = null,
        key = null;

    if (json === null || typeof json !== 'object') {
        return json;
    }
    temp = json.constructor(); // changed
    for (key in json) {
        if (json.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            temp[key] = JSON.clone(json[key]);
        }
    }
    return temp;
};
```

Then you can use your original code but with little changes:

```
var p = {
    id: null
};
for (var copyArray = [], i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    copyArray.push(JSON.clone(p));
    copyArray[i].id = copyArray.length - 1;
}
console.log(copyArray);
```

Comment: why down-vote this answer?