# React, TypeScript, Next.js. Changing all record to last once in static array

Tags: arrays, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have problem with updating my array. When I click button second time and again I have only two or more records, same like last one I added. Someone knows the solution?

In the pictures can you se results of this function in console.

[First time exit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8Wk3.png)

[second time exit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8Wk3.png)

```
class Advertisement {
    advertisment:IAdvertisment = {
        id: 0,
        name: "",
        description: "",
        date: new Date()
    };

    private static ad:[IAdvertisment];
  
    add(id: Number, name: String, description: String, date: Date):void {
        this.advertisment.id = id;
        this.advertisment.name = name;
        this.advertisment.description = description;
        this.advertisment.date = date;

        if (Advertisement.ad) {
            Advertisement.ad.push(this.advertisment);
        }
        else {
            Advertisement.ad = [this.advertisment];
        }
    }

    get():[IAdvertisment]{
        return Advertisement.ad;
    }
}
```

```
class AddAdvertisment extends React.Component <any, any> {
    private advertisment;

    constructor(props, state:IAdvertisment){
        super(props);
        this.onButtonClick = this.onButtonClick.bind(this);
        this.state = state;
        this.advertisment = new Advertisement();
    }


    onButtonClick(){
        this.advertisment.add(this.getAmount(), this.state.name, this.state.description, this.state.date);
    }
 ...

   render() {
        return (<div>
        <input id="name" onChange={this.updateName.bind(this)} ></input>
        <input id="description" onChange={this.updateDescription.bind(this)} ></input>
        <input type="date" id="date" onChange={this.updateDate.bind(this)} ></input>
        <button className={styles.menu_button} onClick={this.onButtonClick.bind(this)}>Add</button>
        </div>);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know. I must create object ones for every time.

```
class Advertisement {
 private static ad:[IAdvertisment];

 add(id: number, name: string, description: string, date: Date):void{

let advertisment:IAdvertisment = {
  id: id,
  name: name,
  description: description,
  date: new Date()
};

if(Advertisement.ad){
  
  Advertisement.ad.push(advertisment);

  console.log(Advertisement.ad);
  
}
else{
  Advertisement.ad = [advertisment];
}
};
```

[Push Object in Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32175356/push-object-in-array)

Comment: Could you put you email here, like "mariusz. at gmail etc"